# How to write OleDbCommand to get only distinct rows?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I just want to have rows that has distinct ManufacturerPartNumber from my excel sheet.

So that, I gave my command text like this:

```
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT Name, DISTINT [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price From [" + SheetName + "] WHERE [ManufacturerPartNumber] IS NOT NULL";
```

But this's not working, and if I changed `DISTINCT [ManufacturerPartNumber]` to `ManufacturerPartNumber`, it works. And it returns duplicated rows which I don't want to happen.

This's the error I got:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'DISTINCT [ManufacturerPartNumber]'.
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

My Excel sheet

```
Name        ManufacturerPartNumber      Price
PenDrive    AGBN514A                    5.4
HardDisk    NKDNKHS5                    9.6
DataCard    AGBN514A                    6.3
```

//here AGBN514A appeared two times, that's in PenDrive and DataCard

Expected output

```
Name        ManufacturerPartNumber      Price
PenDrive    AGBN514A                    5.4
HardDisk    NKDNKHS5                    9.6
```

//it should omit the ManufacturerPartNumbers

Thanks

Comment: Ok so the issue here is that you have the same ManufacturerPartNumber with 2 different names. How do you know which one to omit?

Comment: 'Take the first one, omit others' This was the command to me.

Comment: updated answer with sql to remove the unwanted row.

Comment: I got this error now: "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)."

Comment: I've added square brackets around the ManufacturerPartNumber in the second select. "ManufacturerPartNumbers" maybe a reserved word.

Comment: Now also getting the same error: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the Tsql work?

i've only ever seen distinct used like this before

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price From ...
```

UPDATE

And i've just noticed you're missing a "c" from DISTINCT.

UPDATE 2:

try this SQL:

```
select Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price 
from (
   select Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price ,
      row_number() over (partition by [ManufacturerPartNumber] order by     [ManufacturerPartNumber]) as row_number
   from  test
   ) as rows
where row_number = 1
```

Update 3:

You are trying to select `from test` which is my test table. You'll want to substitute for your sheetname.

```
cmdExcel.CommandText = "select Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price from ( select Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price , row_number() over (partition by [ManufacturerPartNumber] order by [ManufacturerPartNumber]) as row_number from  [" + SheetName + "]) as rows where row_number = 1"
```

Comment: I've now added that 'c'

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price From ... returns duplicated rows which I don't want to happen. I don't want duplicate ManufacturerPartNumber's. :-(

Comment: Could you update you're sql to use group by on the ManufacturerPartNumber ?

Comment: SELECT Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price From [" + SheetName + "] WHERE [ManufacturerPartNumber] IS NOT NULL group by ManufacturerPartNumber, Name, Price

Comment: Could you edit your question with some sample of the data you're seeing and what you want to see?

Comment: Yes Dominic. I've added now. Thanks.

Comment: cmdExcel.CommandText = "select Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price from (   select Name, [ManufacturerPartNumber],Price ,      row_number() over (partition by [ManufacturerPartNumber] order by     [ManufacturerPartNumber]) as row_number   from  test   ) as rows where row_number = 1";